# ReadOnlyCollection current item

Tags: wpf

I'm using MVVM pattern and C#, I public a ReadOnlyCollection property from View-Model, 
In View, there is a TabControl that ItemsSource property is Binding to this ReadOnlyCollection Property.
How can I know which item is being selected from View-Model?
If ReadOnlyCollection cannot do this, what type should i use?
Thank you.

Comment: do you search for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels ??

Comment: no, i'm sorry. Next time i will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the `TabControl` to an additional property in your ViewModel.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all the properties of `TabControl`.