# TabControl which is bound to an ObservableCollection MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

I am currently working on a project using MVVM pattern and can't find anywhere a solution how to bind an ObservableCollection to a TabControl which has a template for an item of it.

For example, this is where I got so far:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnStringBufferOC}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                   <!-- Controls here -->
                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabContro.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This however only partialy works. It creates controls in the tab header area instead of the tab content area. I would want to bind each item to a new tab which has a header of a bound source from OC, for example:

```
Header="{Binding Name}"
```

And in the content area of each tab I would like to have controls, which have contents bound from the ObservableCollection in this example ConnStringBufferOC. So every tab has same controls only content bound to the controls is different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `ContentTemplate` for tab content and `ItemTemplate` for tab header

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConnStringBufferOC}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                <!-- Controls here -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Hmm this should be working, but for some reason the textblock's text isn't displayed in the header. But when I try to bind the same property to the content area it displays it.

Comment: It was working when I tested it. Do you change `Style` or `Template` for `TabItem` that you did not mention in your question?

Comment: Yes, the theme I'm using is customized, thanks for the notification. I'll check what can I do.