# WPF Tab Control with MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf

I am new in WPF, I want to use Tab control with MVVM pattern, Tabs will generate dynamically, I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels#_=_)
However I want to display different datagrid in each tab, Like if I have four tabs T1, T2, T3,T4
I want to have dg1,dg2,dg3 and dg4 respectively
How can I do this in WPF?ie dynamic content
Number of tabs can varies, they can be only 1 tab or more than 1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to use a region manager, register the tabcontrol as region and the register the views to this region.
have a look at these:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165370/Creating-View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921164(v=pandp.20).aspx

and many more once you google **Prism.RegionManager**