# WPF: Bind Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I am using MVVM, and I am trying to bind a `TabControl's` `ItemsSource`, I used this code:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectComponents}"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMenu, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
```

And for the view model:

```
projectComponents = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
projectComponents.Add(new TabItem()
{

     Content = new ProjectComponentsView()
     {
          DataContext = new ProjectClientHandlerViewModel()
     }
});
```

I used this in a `Silverlight` project and it works just fine, but in `WPF`, I don't know why is it that the content of the `TabItem` does not show.

**EDIT:**

I edited my code to this:

View:

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectComponents}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMenu, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <this:ProjectComponentsView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
 </TabControl>
```

View model:

```
projectComponents = new ObservableCollection<ProjectComponentViewModel>();
projectComponents.Add(new ProductViewsHandlerViewModel());
```

Where `ProjectComponentViewModel` is a base class of `ProductViewsHandlerViewModel`, but it's still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I bind a TabControl to a collection of ViewModels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels)

Comment: I don't think it's the same question, the duplicate you posted is for pattern guidelines, my question is why the binding is not happening, since in Silverlight it did work perfectly

Comment: using TabItem type within your viewmodel is not mvvm. you should have a collection of objects(viewmodels) and bind this to the itemssource of the tabcontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example to get you started

```
public class MainVm : VMBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TabVM> Items { get; set; }
        public VMBase SelectedItem {get;set;} 
        public MainVm()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TabVM>()
            {
                new TabVM(){Header="A",Content = new SomeVm()},
                new TabVM(){Header="B",Content = new SomeVm()},
                new TabVM(){Header="C",Content = new SomeVm()},
                new TabVM(){Header="D",Content = new OtherVm()}
            };
        }
    }

    public class TabVM : VMBase
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public VMBase Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeVm : VMBase{}
    public class OtherVm : VMBase{}
    public class VMBase { }


<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeVm}">
                <TextBlock>SomeVm Template</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OtherVm}">
                <TextBlock>OtherVm Template</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"></ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

templates get selected based on the `ViewModel` type as we set them up in the resources, you should also use a `ViewModel` that represents a `TabItem`, which is `TabVM` in the above snippet.

in the `ItemTemplate` of the tab control you set up the header template and in the `ContentTemplate` you put a `ContentControl` and bind its `Content` to the `Content` property of `TabVM`.

and don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.