# WPF databinding for multilevel tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Please can anyone tell me how to databind a tabcontrol that contains children tabs.
I need to create a **menu** using **tabcontrol**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I bind a TabControl to a collection of ViewModels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels)

Comment: Thank you Maxine,but this is not what really I a masking for.In my situation,I need a way,the easiest, to create,dynamically, a multilevel menu using tabcontrol.Please what you suggest.

Comment: Help us a bit, what have you tried so far and what aren't you able to do?

Comment: Thank you @Maxime for your collaboration
All the examples I found in the net take a simple Object X that contains a string header and a string content then databind an ObservableCollection<X> to a TabControl which result on a onelevel tabcontrol.
What I am not able to do,is how to create tabcontrol with **children tabcontrols**, what's the correct way,respecting MVVM.I mean that each tabcontrol can have sub tabcontrols. I need a way to create a **menu** with tabcontrols.

Comment: Please help,I am so blocked guys :-/

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a help desk. If you don't show any effort, don't expect us to to your job for you.

Comment: @Henrique ,I know that and I am not expecting a solution for my work.I thought that my issue is clear,I just need to create like a menu,but using tabcontrol.I am using MVVM in my application.The examples posted in net speak about a simple data binding to a tabcontrol,an observable collection of headers and simple content.there are no samples that databind to a tacontrol that its tabitems can contain a tabcontrol instead of content.It's a kind of creating menu but using tabcontrol.

Comment: Hello team,please I am still waiting a little white light :/

Comment: Provide some example data.

Comment: @OmegaMan,I need to create a menu like the one used in **Microsoft ZUNE app**.The menu is developed using *tabcontrol*.I can have or many levels in my menu.I did not find a way to do it using MVVM.

Comment: Guys please anyone has idea?