# MVVM select new Tab from TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to select tab from tab control after creating it.

XAML:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" Name="Items">
      <TabControl.Resources>
      </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public int SelectedTabIndex
{
   get
   {
      return Items.Count - 1;
   }
   set { ; }
}
public void AddTab()
{
   var chart = new ChartViewModel(this.eventAggregator, this.windowManager);
   NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedTabIndex);
}
```

`ChartViewModel` is a class inherited from `Caliburn.Micro.Screen`, `MainViewModel` inherits from `Caliburn.Micro.Conductor<Caliburn.Micro.Screen>.Collection.OneActive`

The tab is created properly, but it is not selected after that.

Comment: Binding to SelectedIndex (or similar) is imho a code smell in wpf.  It's always easier and cleaner to use ItemsSource/SelectedItem to manage selection.  Also, for a cleaner example of how to use the TabControl in an MVVM way, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651542/1228

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your xaml code to something like this,

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="Items">
      <TabControl.Resources>
      </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I had to add a `set` property to `SelectedTabIndex`, but now it works :) Thank you.