# Setting Datacontext of viewmodel not in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I have a `WPF` application using `mah metro` where I have a `tab control`

```
  <Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabItem Header="Manual Control">
            <view:ManualControlView DataContext="{Binding ManualControlViewModel}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Set up">
            <view:SetupView DataContext="{Binding SetupViewModel}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
```

I am setting the `datacontext` in the `TabItem`.  I am creating a `TcpCllient` and passing that reference to each `ViewModel`.  When I am doing this in the constructor everything works fine.

```
  public MainViewModel()
    {
        _client = new TcpClient(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
        _client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
        _master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(_client);

        ManualControlViewModel = new ManualControlViewModel(_master);
        SetupViewModel = new SetupViewModel(_master);

    }
```

However, I don't wish to create the `TcpClient` in the constructor.  Instead I wish to create it when I hit a "Connect" button in my window.  However, when I click my "Connect" button to execute a `OnConnect` method to do this my views are not getting set to the `datacontext`.

```
  private void OnConnect(object obj)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
        _client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
        _master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(_client);
        Connected = _client.Connected;

        ManualControlViewModel = new ManualControlViewModel(_master);
        SetupViewModel = new SetupViewModel(_master);          

        StartReadingInfo();
    }
```

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels/5651542#5651542 which illustrates how to work with the TabControl using MVVM.  Your button should be bound to an ICommand within your view model (whichever is appropriate), and *that* should update the other view models already bound to the UI.  Your properties should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to inform the UI that property values have ... changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update properties of ViewModel, you should notify Control that properties changed.

```
        public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public SetupViewModel SetupViewModel 
            {
                get { return m_SetupViewModel; }
                set
                {
                    m_SetupViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public ManualControlViewModel ManualControlViewModel
            {
                get { return m_ManualControlViewModel; }
                set
                {
                    m_ManualControlViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnConnect(object obj)
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
                _client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                _master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(_client);
                Connected = _client.Connected;

                ManualControlViewModel = new ManualControlViewModel(_master);
                SetupViewModel = new SetupViewModel(_master);

                StartReadingInfo();
            }

            private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }

            private ManualControlViewModel m_ManualControlViewModel;
            private SetupViewModel m_SetupViewModel;
        }
```