# WPF Navigate through child elements or keep track of dynamically created child elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl where I create tabs dynamically. I am finding it difficult to change the title of the TabItem.

```
 <TabControl Name="AttorneysTabControl" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AttorneyTabHeader">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button Width="Auto" UseLayoutRounding="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Click="CloseAttorneysTabButtonClick">
                    <Image Source="/images/close-cross-thin-circular-button/close-cross-thin-circular-button16.png" Height="16"></Image>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AttorneyTabContent">
            <local:AttorneyDetails></local:AttorneyDetails>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
```

For each TabItem I set a `HeaderTemplate` from the `TabControl.Resources` like this;

```
newTabItem.HeaderTemplate = (System.Windows.DataTemplate)AttorneysTabControl.FindResource("AttorneyTabHeader");
```

But I don't know how to change the contents of the TabItem header once the template has been set. I have tried using DataContext for the TabItem if that's the way to do it but it did not work, so that I could just use `Binding` in the template. That will be a lot easier.

Comment: You can define `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` which is `TabItem` and where you can change/bind `Header`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels

Comment: I am using `newTabItem.HeaderTemplate = (System.Windows.DataTemplate)AttorneysTabControl.FindResource("AttorneyTabHeader");` to set the HeaderTemplate. This template is within the TabControl itself.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I can't bind the TabControl to a model view since I already have an existing tab which I use as an index. So I can only add and remove new ones.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"..that sounds like you're binding to a collection unless it's a typo. If you could post some snippets of your DataContext, it might help.

Comment: That does not work since the TextBlock is part of a template which is added dynamically. This is similar to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should normally write (first line is your unchanged code):

```
newTabItem.HeaderTemplate = (System.Windows.DataTemplate)AttorneysTabControl.FindResource("AttorneyTabHeader");
var tabItemData = new TabItemData() { Name="Initial name"} ;
newTabItem.DataContext = tabItemData;
```

And then once you need to update the tab header:

```
tabItemData.Name = "New name".
```

If that didn't work, that'd probably because your `TabItemData.Name` property doesn't notify of its changes. So make sure that your `TabItemData` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that the Name property notifies. Example:

```
public class TabItemData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string name;
  public string Name
  {
    get { return this.name; }

    set 
    {
        if (value != this.name)
        {
            this.name= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }

}
```

In case you're lost I suggest reading the *Managing data in a WPF application* chapter of my [Learn WPF MVVM](https://leanpub.com/learnwpf) book.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I have created a class `private class TabItemData : INotifyPropertyChanged`. Can I add DataContext to any element and bind a class to that element in WPF?

Comment: Yes you can. That's why I have you write "newTabItem.DataContext = tabItemData". You did fine with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, now just make sure that the Name property in that classe notifies of its changes so that the UI automatically updates when your code changes its value. See my updated answer with notification code.