# WPF: How to dynamically create controls and edit controls in code

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, ironpython

I have a xaml which contains a tab control (Name="MyTabControl"). I'm a beginner with wpf and in code and I want to dynamically add tab items that I then add a list box to each created tab item. Below is the code I have so far.

```
ListBox listbox = new ListBox()
TabItem tab = new TabItem()
tab.AddChild(listbox)

MyTabControl.Add(tab)
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how dynamically create new tabs that also would add a list box to each new tab and the new tabs then added to MyTabControl.
Then, I would want to be able to access each list box control, individually, in each tab to edit the list box content.

How is this done in code? How can i access the created list box controls to edit them?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Looks like I need to research and learn up on MVVM in order to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF/UWP and XAML are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so will miss about 90% of it's power and run into issues at every other corner.

In MVVM this would be simply a mater of Exposing a Collection and having a Tempalte targetting that type. ListBoxes might even have a custom Template system, but using ListBoxes might no longer be nessesary - any container can expose a Collection.

If you plan on learning MVVM, mid to longertem you should learn MVVM. I wrote a [short intro a few years back](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf), that should help you going. Help for people not following MVVM is parse on the Forum.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a violation of the MVVM principles WPF is built around to build a UI in this way. Instead, consider a solution similar to the one proposed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels). They do a good job of explaining both what to do, and *why* we do it this way.