# How can I update the UI (view) based on a method from viewmodel while still following MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am fairly new to WPF, C#, and the MVVM structure, so excuse my ignorance. I am simply trying to create a new tab when a file is opened. My logic is all in the ViewModel including opening files which is called through binding in the XAML file, so I am confused how I am supposed to get the view to create a new tab once a file is opened without communication between the two. Maybe there is something I am missing, maybe my approach is completely incorrect, I'm not sure.

I have recently found a way to bind 2 commands to 1 event, but if it creates a tab every time someone clicks 'open' it will be problematic, especially if the user cancels. I have looked into having the view and ViewModel communicate as there are ways to do so, but I am trying everything possible to avoid that and completely breaking the rules of MVVM.

Comment: You probably use the `TabControl` to show tabs. And the `TabControl` is an `ItemControl`. In this case you can add the observable collection of per-tab sub-view models inside the windows view model, then bind this collection to the `TabControl.ItemSource' property. See here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Also this may be helpful [How do I bind a TabControl to a collection of ViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels)

Comment: @Serg Thank you so much, second link worked and first link gave me some more insight on the topic.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways:

1. TabControl supports ItemsSource and you can simply add a new element to the ObservableCollection from the ViewModel, which will be updated immediately. Example: [How do I bind a TabControl to a collection of ViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels)
2. If the property from the ViewModel supports INotifyPropertyChanged, then you can update it.

```
[Reactive] // ReactiveUI.Fody
public string IsTabVisible { get; private set; }
```

```
<TabItem Visibility={Binding IsTabVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter} />
</TabItem>
```

3. A complicated but good way, using Prism(and partially ReactiveUI) you can make navigation to your tab.

If you are a beginner, then I advise you to use the first method.

Comment: Yup I went with the first method and it works great. Thanks so much!